# Maven cant download spring dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have never had any problem with maven, but after reinstalling Ubuntu system (i got 17.10 right now) i cant download spring depenencies using maven. With gradle works everything fine. When i run command `mvn clean install` on simple Spring Boot project from start.spring.io I got something like that:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building demo3333 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.5.12.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.12.RELEASE.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.5.12.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.12.RELEASE.pom (6.7 kB at 8.0 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-tools/1.5.12.RELEASE/spring-boot-tools-1.5.12.RELEASE.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-tools/1.5.12.RELEASE/spring-boot-tools-1.5.12.RELEASE.pom (1.3 kB at 19 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-parent/1.5.12.RELEASE/spring-boot-parent-1.5.12.RELEASE.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-parent/1.5.12.RELEASE/spring-boot-parent-1.5.12.RELEASE.pom (28 kB at 232 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.5.12.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.5.12.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar (66 kB at 557 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.6.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.6.1.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.6.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.6.1.pom (5.0 kB at 65 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/26/maven-plugins-26.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/26/maven-plugins-26.pom (11 kB at 170 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/25/maven-parent-25.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/25/maven-parent-25.pom (37 kB at 451 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/15/apache-15.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/15/apache-15.pom (15 kB at 218 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.6.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.6.1.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.6.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.6.1.jar (29 kB at 395 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom (8.1 kB at 111 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/23/maven-plugins-23.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/23/maven-plugins-23.pom (9.2 kB at 135 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/22/maven-parent-22.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/22/maven-parent-22.pom (30 kB at 367 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/11/apache-11.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/11/apache-11.pom (15 kB at 183 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.jar (30 kB at 356 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.1.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.1.pom (10 kB at 152 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/24/maven-plugins-24.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/24/maven-plugins-24.pom (11 kB at 164 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/23/maven-parent-23.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/23/maven-parent-23.pom (33 kB at 397 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom (14 kB at 189 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.1.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.1.jar (43 kB at 429 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.18.1/maven-surefire-plugin-2.18.1.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.18.1/maven-surefire-plugin-2.18.1.pom (5.7 kB at 79 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.18.1/surefire-2.18.1.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire/2.18.1/surefire-2.18.1.pom (17 kB at 236 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/26/maven-parent-26.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/26/maven-parent-26.pom (40 kB at 479 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/16/apache-16.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/16/apache-16.pom (15 kB at 220 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.18.1/maven-surefire-plugin-2.18.1.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.18.1/maven-surefire-plugin-2.18.1.jar (37 kB at 481 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.6/maven-jar-plugin-2.6.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.6/maven-jar-plugin-2.6.pom (5.9 kB at 85 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/27/maven-plugins-27.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/27/maven-plugins-27.pom (11 kB at 162 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.6/maven-jar-plugin-2.6.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.6/maven-jar-plugin-2.6.jar (26 kB at 329 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.5.2/maven-install-plugin-2.5.2.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.5.2/maven-install-plugin-2.5.2.pom (6.4 kB at 80 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/25/maven-plugins-25.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/25/maven-plugins-25.pom (9.6 kB at 140 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/24/maven-parent-24.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/24/maven-parent-24.pom (37 kB at 434 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/14/apache-14.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/14/apache-14.pom (15 kB at 213 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.5.2/maven-install-plugin-2.5.2.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.5.2/maven-install-plugin-2.5.2.jar (33 kB at 399 kB/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.12.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.12.RELEASE.pom
```

and it just stops and nothing happens. I though I got something wrong with cretificates maybe? But it downloads some of jars...

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you show us your pom?

Comment: I assume you have some network issues if the download simply stops...

Comment: Can you run maven with `--debug`?